# Disable Magnifing glass in UITextview, but not URL Link and Phone number events

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, ios9

I have an issue with UITextview in iOS9, when i do a longpress on textview it shows the magnifying glass. I tried to disable through UILongPressGestureRecognizer, it completely disables the Link and phone touch events also.

How to Disable only Magnifing glass.

```
 override func addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer .isKindOfClass(UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = false
    }
    super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

the textview will be in a collectionview cell.

Comment: Have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to achieve that. Just override the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` for the `UITextView`. This gesture-recognizer object is about to begin processing touches to determine if its gesture is occurring.
The only tricky part is to properly recognize delegate which is assigned to the magnifier activation.

---

I've successfully tested with: `UITextGestureClusterLoupe`. Here is the working example (**Swift 4**):

```
override public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
{
    if let gestureDelegate = gestureRecognizer.delegate {

        if(gestureDelegate.description.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("UITextGestureClusterLoupe"))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine! To make it more Swift-like I would remove the semicolons ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to Vlada's anwser, for my code I found the delegate assigned to the magnifier activation is "UITextLoupeInteraction"

Here is my code:

```
open override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer:  UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let gestureDelegate = gestureRecognizer.delegate {
        print(gestureDelegate.description)
        if(gestureDelegate.description.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("_UIKeyboardBasedTextSelectionInteraction")){
            return false
        }

        if(gestureDelegate.description.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("UITextLoupeInteraction")){
            return false
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

My development environment: swift4, Xcode10.1, iOS 12.1

Answer (score 0):

The code seems right but you need to override the `gestureRecognizer` for the textView, not the superclass. Change `super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)` to `yourTextView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)` and place it in the view controller containing an outlet to your text view(if it's not there already).

Comment: i subclassed the UITextview, that y am using "super". The textview will be in a CollectionViewcell.